# jQuery Mobile: listview(refresh) for div tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm pretty newbie with jQuery mobile (and JS :)), excuse if I'm saying something that looks too easy. I've searched through the Internet for two days now and haven't find a solution.

I want to know if there's some function that does the same that $(#someList).listview('refresh') but for div tags. I've got two div tags and when I dinamycally change its contents they loose the styling.

Code:

```
function muestraFicha() {
    var categoriaFicha = "Ciencia / Matemáticas";
    var preguntaFicha = "Si un tren eléctrico sale de Valencia dirección Barcelona a 60Km/h con viento norte de 30Km/h ¿Hacia qué dirección saldrá el viento de su chimenea?";
    var respuestaFicha = "En ninguna dirección, es un tren eléctrico y por lo tanto no despide humo";
    var divRespuesta = "<div data-role='collapsible' data-theme='b' data-content-theme='c'>"

    $("#fichaRespuesta").empty(); //vaciamos la ficha
    $("#fichaRespuesta").append("<h4> Respuesta </h4>");
    $("#fichaRespuesta").append("<p>" + respuestaFicha + "</p>");

    $("#fichaPregunta").empty();
    $("#fichaPregunta").append("<h3>" + categoriaFicha + "</h3>");
    $("#fichaPregunta").append("<p>" + preguntaFicha + "</p>");
}
```

So, at the end of the function I need something a the .listview('refresh') or the html is only styled the first time the function is called.

The divs that lose style are fichaRespuesta and fichaPregunta.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have jQuery Mobile style any new DOM element, you can use the `.trigger('create');` function:

> New “create” event: Easily enhance all widgets at once
>
> While the page plugin no longer calls each plugin specifically, it
>   does dispatch a “pagecreate” event, which most widgets use to
>   auto-initialize themselves. As long as a widget plugin script is
>   referenced, it will automatically enhance any instances of the widgets
>   it finds on the page, just like before. For example, if the selectmenu
>   plugin is loaded, it will enhance any selects it finds within a newly
>   created page.
>
> This structure now allows us to add a new create event that can be
>   triggered on any element, saving you the task of manually initializing
>   each plugin contained in that element. Until now, if a developer
>   loaded in content via Ajax or dynamically generated markup, they
>   needed to manually initialize all contained plugins (listview button,
>   select, etc.) to enhance the widgets in the markup.
>
> Now, our handy create event will initialize all the necessary plugins
>   within that markup, just like how the page creation enhancement
>   process works. If you were to use Ajax to load in a block of HTML
>   markup (say a login form), you can trigger create to automatically
>   transform all the widgets it contains (inputs and buttons in this
>   case) into the enhanced versions. The code for this scenario would be:
>
> **$( ...new markup that contains widgets... ).appendTo( ".ui-page"
>   ).trigger( "create" );**
>
> Create vs. refresh: An important distinction
>
> Note that there is an important difference between the create event
>   and refresh method that some widgets have. The create event is suited
>   for enhancing raw markup that contains one or more widgets. The
>   refresh method that some widgets have should be used on existing
>   (already enhanced) widgets that have been manipulated programmatically
>   and need the UI be updated to match.
>
> For example, if you had a page where you dynamically appended a new
>   unordered list with data-role=listview attribute after page creation,
>   triggering create on a parent element of that list would transform it
>   into a listview styled widget. If more list items were then
>   programmatically added, calling the listview’s refresh method would
>   update just those new list items to the enhanced state and leave the
>   existing list items untouched.

Link to the above information: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/08/03/jquery-mobile-beta-2-released/

Also I notice you are using the same selectors consecutively, you can greatly improve the performance of your code by chaining together the calls to selectors, like so:

Change:

```
$("#fichaRespuesta").empty(); //vaciamos la ficha
$("#fichaRespuesta").append("<h4> Respuesta </h4>");
$("#fichaRespuesta").append("<p>" + respuestaFicha + "</p>");

$("#fichaPregunta").empty();
$("#fichaPregunta").append("<h3>" + categoriaFicha + "</h3>");
$("#fichaPregunta").append("<p>" + preguntaFicha + "</p>");
```

To:

```
$("#fichaRespuesta").empty().append("<h4> Respuesta </h4><p>" + respuestaFicha + "</p>");

$("#fichaPregunta").empty().append("<h3>" + categoriaFicha + "</h3><p>" + preguntaFicha + "</p>");
```

Notice I removed one of the `.append()` calls since it creates extra overhead to call it twice in a row; instead I put the HTML for both `.append()` calls in a single call.

If you really want to get into making your code performance improve, cache the selectors so they only have to be looked-up once, like so:

```
var $fichaRespuesta = $('#fichaRespuesta'),
    $fichaPregunta  = $('#fichaPregunta');
function muestraFicha() {
    /*I removed your extra code to make this easier to read*/

    $fichaRespuesta.empty().append("<h4> Respuesta </h4><p>" + respuestaFicha + "</p>");

    $fichaPregunta.empty().append("<h3>" + categoriaFicha + "</h3><p>" + preguntaFicha + "</p>");
```

Comment: Wow! great answer, not only solved my needs but also helped me to improve app performance! Thank you Jasper.

Comment: You're welcome. I was just looking at the above code again and I realized that calling `.empty().append(<append code>)` is the same as calling `.html(<append code>)`. Docs for `.html(<append string>)`: http://api.jquery.com/html/